# Is it possible to transfer Google Analytics data from one account to another using data import?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to transfer data from one GA account to another.

I know merging the data from two accounts is impossible and there is 'move property' option. We also do not have GA 360.

However, I am wondering if it would be possible to export data from the old account and use data import feature on the new account to transfer that data.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Data Import lets you upload data from external sources and combine it with data you collect via Analytics, so you cannot import session metrics such as sessions or users but you can import additional data to enrich that information that must already be in Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible. Looks like you already know about the only option available.